# How to restore external drive from Time Machine backup under Monterey

Tags: macos, mac, backup, time-machine

Previously, it was straightforward to restore an external drive from a Time Machine backup:

```
sudo tmutil restore /Volumes/backups/Backups.backupdb/MacBookPro/Latest/USB-old/* /Volumes/USB-new
```

Under Monterey, however, Time Machine's structure has changed. There is no "latest" folder, there are snapshots, and there is no way to navigate the backup drive's structure from Terminal.

I would love some advice about this as my external drive failed and I would really like to get it restored ASAP. Thanks!